# how do plants evolve to eat creatures

Tags: planets, evolution, flora

I have a idea for a plant on my world Chlorea. It is inspired by Venus fly traps and the plant that smells like rotten meat that attract bugs, but I want to know why and how did they evolve this way and how far can it can go. I don't need a very detailed answer but just enough to know what I'm looking for, and does it change if megafauna and flora are involved

Comment: https://treehozz.com/how-is-the-stinking-corpse-lily-adapted-to-the-rainforest

Comment: FYI, this is at least your second question which could have been answered with a simple internet search (the other being the plants shooting seeds). We greatly appreciate when users do their own homework before asking here.

Comment: no i knew about the seeds i just needed to know if was to complex this i couldent find anything about if for some reason maybe i was typing it wrong idk

Answer (score 2):

Predatory plants generally evolve due to lack of nutrients in the soil. Venus fly traps live in the swamp and pitcher plants live in jungles, both very nutrient-poor areas. Plants usually evolve predation as a way to supplement their diet with nitrogen and other nutrients from the dead animals, not as an energy source.

I would say that mice or other small rodents are the largest creatures predatory plants could feasibly consume. The larger the animal, the harder it will be for the plants to capture them. Furthermore, larger the animal, the harder for the plant to digest before it rots, since plants cannot chew. At some point, it stops being worth the effort.

Comment: but remember there is mega flora and funa so i feel like the plant would probely be bigger then the animal aslo thanks for the info

Comment: Square cube law still applies. The larger a creature, the larger the volume to surface area ratio. Unless your plant has some method to chew, it will have a hard time digesting like carnivorous plants here on earth (by submerging the prey in digestive enzymes), since digestive enzymes can only consume from the surface of the prey.

Comment: @ErikSanchez Also, when the prey gets large, then the plant will start having to deal with scavenging animals, who typically have a higher energy budget,  that will notice the plant eating a dead thing, and try to eat the dead thing before the plant is done with it. Almost nothing is going to claw a fly out of a venus flytrap,  The effort to get a rabbit carcass out of a jupiter rabbittrap may be worth it.

Comment: thank you for the information

Comment: A plant has no problem with their prey rotting - it frees up the nutrients, which leak out.

Answer (score 2):

well maybe there was a drought for a while on the planet and most plants did not survive but the small population of carnivorous plants did but the animals started to eat them so over time they grew bigger and evolved to eat larger animals for survival

(Give me your thoughts)

Comment: i like the idea and since the planet has mega flora and fuana and high oxygen the plants could get ginormous but there is a problem of finding enough food ill figure it out but this was helpful